# Duplicate a whole database on the same server?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We are running a service where we have to setup a new database for each new site. The database is exactly the same so we can simply dump from a backup file or clone from a sample database (which is created only for clone purpose, no transaction will be run there thus no worry about corrupting data) from the same server. The database it self contains around 100 tables and with some data, taking around 1-2mins to import, which is too slow.

I'm trying to find a way to do it as fast as possible, the first thought came to mind was to copy the files within the sample database data_dir, but it seems like I also need to somehow edit the table lists or mysql wont be able to read my new database's tables eventhough it still shows them there.

Comment: How many gigabytes of data are being copied? Can you show me what you're doing specifically that takes 1-2 minutes?

Comment: sure, right now it's a simple restore db using mysql -uusername -ppassword datatabase.dump.sql. I also set autocomit, unique_check, foreign_key_checks to OFF

Comment: Well that explains why it's slow then, you are reading the whole database from the disk, converting it to mysql source code insert statements, then writing the whole database to the disk in a very inefficient format, then reading it from the disk again, parsing a huge number of sql queries, executing them, and finally writing all the data once again. Terrible idea. That is not how you duplicate a database.

Answer (score 2):

You're duplicating the database the wrong way, it will be much faster if you do it properly.

Here is how you duplicate a database:

```
create database new_database;
create table new_database.table_one select * from source_database.table_one;
create table new_database.table_two select * from source_database.table_two;
create table new_database.table_three select * from source_database.table_three;
...
```

I just did a performance test, this takes 81 seconds to duplicate 750MB of data across 7 million table rows. Presumably your database is smaller than that?

I don't think you are going to find anything faster. One thing you could do is already have a queue of duplicate databases on standby ready to be picked up and used at any time. So you don't need to create a new database at all, you just rename an existing database from a queue of available ones. And have a cron job running to make sure the queue never runs empty.

Answer (score -2):

Why mysql not able to read or what you changes in table lists?

I think there may be problem of permissions to read by mysql, otherwise it would be fine..

Thanks

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work that way. Remember I'm trying to duplicate 1 single database, not the whole database server, so I only copied files, but then mysql also stores list of database's tablenames and such at other places which cannot be duplicated that easy.

Comment: This could be possible only if you have all myisam tables ..
then just simple all myisam table files in new database folder.

Comment: Unfortunately we are using innodb in this case :(